# How to change tab with Bootstrap & Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change tab with on `#rootwizard`, I have this code, but I can not go to tab1 with jquery.

```
$('#rootwizard').find("a [href *= 'tab1']").trigger('click');
```

Leads me tab2
tab2 leads me to tab3 and so on.

```
$('#rootwizard .finish').click(function() {
    alert('Finished!, Starting over!');
    $('#rootwizard').find("a[href*='tab1']").trigger('click');
});
```

This doesn't work for the first position. *I need go to **tab1**, but go to **SECOND***.

tab1 `-->` SECOND.

tab2 `-->` THIRD.

**( I need tab1 `-->` FIRST )**

[**Here**](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-finishbutton.html) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the index. The first tab starts with index 0, and the second one with 1 and so on, so i think you should do

```
$('#rootwizard .finish').click(function() {
        alert('Finished!, Starting over!');
        $('#rootwizard').find("a[href*='tab0']").trigger('click');
    });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

this works fine !

$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('next')